# ClosureScript repl under lein fails on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with FileNotFoundException

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, leiningen, clojurescript

Trying to get the closurescript repl up with lein under a lein project directory, on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS all-up-to-date.  I have a basic hello-world project that I created with `lein new hello-world`, and a custom `project.clj` (listed below).  The same set-up works fine on Mac OS X 7 for me.

```
$ lein trampoline cljsbuild repl-rhino Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate leiningen/core/main__init.class or leiningen/core/main.clj on classpath:  (subproject.clj:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5441)   
        ...
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate leiningen/core/main__init.class or leiningen/core/main.clj on classpath: 
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:412)

$ lein --version
Leiningen 1.7.1 on Java 1.6.0_27 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
```

project.clj:

```
(defproject hello-world "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
                 [org.clojure/clojurescript "0.0-2030"]]
  :plugins [[lein-cljsbuild "1.0.0-alpha2"]]
  :cljsbuild {:builds []})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you have to use the `lein cljsbuild` (but I think you have to update the version of your lein-cljsbuild plugin declared in your project.clj [I am using: 0.3.0], and you have to run with lein 2 also)exec to run repl or compilations (once, auto) tasks

Here you can check out more info about this leiningen tool https://github.com/emezeske/lein-cljsbuild

And here you can read the @dnolen advise about  the use of this tool 
[How to Debug ClojureScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990077/how-to-debug-clojurescript)

Comment: Great, works!  Here's what worked (I keep 'lein2' as a separate executable):

First: `$ lein2 cljsbuild`
Then, after `lein2` does its work:

`$ lein2 trampoline cljsbuild repl-rhino`

This gives me a working repl prompt.